# Convert simple code from Perl to PHP (issue)

Tags: php, perl, function, pack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Perl code to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220444/convert-a-perl-code-to-php)

Hello all,
I don't know much in Perl and I'm having problems converting a simple code from Perl to PHP:
here is the code:

```
pack("SSA12AC4L",
                $id,
                $loc,
                $name,
                'ar',
                $get->getIP),
                time));
```

I'd appreaciate if anyone could help me in converting this to PHP.
Thanks a lot.